# Как создать URL-адрес моего HTML

Tags: html, html5

Я только начал учить html,делаю сайт который имеет ссылки на все эпизоды и тд по ЗВ. Как мне сделать что бы мой друг по ссылке мог хайти на этот сайт?

Comment: Выложить html файлы на хостинг.

Comment: купить домен, хостинг, подключить домен к хостингу и залить свои файлы на хостинг

Comment: Ваш сайт на хостинге?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все что вам нужно это зарегистрироваться на https://pages.github.com/ , создать свой репозиторий и превартить его в сайт, более детально описано тут [github pages](https://medium.com/nuances-of-programming/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-github-pages-e0f3c258ee22)

Answer (score 0):

Я вижу 2 варианта:

1. Ищете **хостинг**(по сути другой компьютер, с которого все смогут "скачать" ваш сайт и посмотреть на него в браузере. Смысл хостинга в том, что он работает всегда и ваш сайт будет доступен всегда. Теоретически вы можете использовать вместо хостинга свой компьютер, но тогда он будет должет быть всегда включен, да и для вас это будет в общем трудно) и получаете **домен**(адрес в интернете, по которому пользователи смогут найти хостинг, на котором лежит ваш сайт и собственно зайти на него).
2. Вы можете отправить файлы вашего сайта вашему другу, например в виде архива через мессенджер. Ваш друг откроет эти файлы через браузер и посмотрит.

Я думаю для вас лучше 2 вариант. Сейчас заморачиваться выбором хостинга и тем более домена не стоит. Хоть они и бывают бесплатные, но вам пока уж лучше отправлять архивы. Это самый простой вариант.